# Exporting BLOB data from a sqlite table into a CSV file or (another extension) without corrupting binary data

Tags: c#, sqlite, csv, export, blob

I've tried exporting a table which it has 5 TEXT columns and 1 BLOB column, this last column is used for storing images.

But, when I export the database table into a csv file (by using the software SQLite Database Browser) the information of this columns is transformed into TEXT as well. (Perhaps I was wrong)

How can I export BLOB data from my sqlite db table to a sql server table?

I will be so thankful if you help me. Please!!  (I'm programming a c# application, but It doesn't matter, because I'm using SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1.exe to see the data.)

Comment: Why CSV, and not a copy of the DB file?

Comment: Because Someone else needs to manage the data in other formats by using Excel for instance.

Comment: Excel does not handle binary data.

Comment: So, What do you suggest to me?

Comment: Change that requirement.

Comment: You told me about creating a copy of my DB file. How do you merge two compatible db tables with BLOB information?

Comment: Why is merging needed for a backup?

Comment: @JhoanSebastianSierraHernnde I think that you need to do more research and gain further understanding on how systems work such as database and what the different datatypes are for those specific columns in a db table. If you are unsure about a backup or how to make a copy you might want to consult with / hire a DBA

Comment: @MethodMan Ok, I change my Question. How to transform my sqlite table (with BLOB data) into a SQL server table? is that possible?